# Domain path inside PEPWilma's configuration file

Tags: fiware, authzforce

I'm trying to use Fiware PEPWilma and AuthZForce to ensure Security Level 2 on my service.

I'm struggling to have it set as I can't find a guide/reference material explaining how to configure them. Even their guides are lacking a lot of information.

The attribute I'm trying to understand now is `path` of `config.azf={}` inside pepwilma's `config.js` configuration file. What does this attribute expect to receive?

In the sample `config.js` file I've got the value is:

> path: '/authzforce/domains/v10rvAGjEeaiEQJCrBEAAg/pdp'

But I don't know what is this path for and how to get my domain id.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, you have a deprecated version of Wilma. Please, download the latest version. You will see that now the domain is filled automatically when checking token validity with Keyrock

Comment: Great, I see you guys just released an update. I'll download the latest version and test it. But what should I put in this attribute in my config file?

Answer (score 0):

This path used to be the URL path to the AuthzForce domain (so a full URL would be something like `http://localhost:8080/authzforce/domains/v10rvAGjEeaiEQJCrBEAAg/pdp`) that is used for authorization decisions (based on the authorization policies in that domain).

In the latest PEP Proxy v5.4, this attribute no longer exists. The PEP used the path `/authzforce-ce/domains/${domainId}`, where `domainId` - as Alvaro mentioned in a comment - is filled automatically from the OAuth token expected in the incoming HTTP request and which has been validated in the previous authentication phase. Actually, the domainId in the token is linked to the applicationId (each application has a specific AuthzForce domainId).